# How to insert all data rather than getting 1 row only

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to insert all the data from my table column of my database, but right now im getting only one row / or in short I want to get all the data column not only 1 row, im using this code:

```
     Try
     For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
     networkconn.Open()    
     Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO networkdatabase.table1(data,result) values('" & dt.Rows(0).Item("data").ToString & "','" & dt.Rows(0).Item("result").ToString() & "')", networkconn)
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     networkconn.close
     Next
     Catch ex As Exception
     End Try
```

**This is my table**

```
 +------------+----------+
 |    data    |  result  |
 +------------+----------+
 | 1234567890 | PASSED   |
 | Test       | PASSED   |
 | SAMPLE     | FAILED   |
 | test       | FAILED   |
 | GGGGGG     | PASSED   |
 | 1111111111 | PASSED   |
 | XXXXXXXXXX | PASSED   |
 +------------+----------+
```

**My output**

```
 +------------+----------+
 |    data    |  result  |
 +------------+----------+
 | 1234567890 | PASSED   |
 +------------+----------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
 +------------+----------+
 |    data    |  result  |
 +------------+----------+
 | 1234567890 | PASSED   |
 | Test       | PASSED   |
 | SAMPLE     | FAILED   |
 | test       | FAILED   |
 | GGGGGG     | PASSED   |
 | 1111111111 | PASSED   |
 | XXXXXXXXXX | PASSED   |
 +------------+----------+
```

Comment: use [loop](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for-vbnet)

Comment: How about: `For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just make an SQL command with more lines. Passing more than one command in one string is allowed. Just separate by semicolon

```
 INSERT INTO table values(x,y,z); 
 INSERT INTO table values(x,y,z); 
 INSERT INTO table values(x,y,z);
```

Comment: I know this simple logic but im doing my code, getting data from local host so that i used data table then transfer to network server

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert every row that in the td like this :

```
        For i = 0 To dt.rows.count - 1
          Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO networkdatabase.table1(data,result) values('" & dt.Rows(i).Item("data").ToString & "','" & dt.Rows(i).Item("result").ToString() & "')", ServerCN)
       Next
```

Comment: It is Error when it will go to the next row.